# Using a .txt file to store data in iOS?

Tags: ios, iphone, text, plist

I am making a few apps that all require pre-set data to be loaded into the app. This data does not need to be changed or altered in any way as the app progresses - it is simply the data that the app runs on (to give more detail, it is questions for a quiz app). I have elected to use .txt files to store this data, but I wanted to know if this is the best way to do this? Text files allow me to easily change the data without coding. I can also copy and paste from normal documents. Is storing data in this way a good practice, or should I try to hard-code the data/ use a p-list?

Comment: this is a subjective question imho: it all depends on how fragile the .txt file parsing in your code is.

Comment: I apologize, as I would agree to an extent. Assuming I can parse it without a problem (which I have been able to), is there anything wrong with using a text file? People seem to flock to core data and p-lists (especially p-lists for pre-set data), but no one seems to use text files. I just wanted to know if there was a reason (i.e. speed, fragility as you mentioned etc.).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question depends a lot on how you want to implement your code.

.TXT files might work well, but what happens to the memory requirements when you pass a certain number of questions (e.g. more than 100, or even 10?).  Also, what kind of structure are you using in memory to hold the question?  If it's a NSDictionary or NSArray, perhaps a `.plist` file might work better for you.

Raw NSData, or some proprietary format, might work best if you have a lot of non-modifiable questions and you want to try to compress the data down as much as possible (which is a consideration on the low memory / low disk space iPhones).

CoreData might come in handy if you want to store a ***lot*** of questions and answers, especially those that users are manually entering in or managing.

Comment: Thanks. I have about 700 questions and I don't seem to have a memory issue yet. However, I'd like to make the app as efficient as possible. How would I write to a plist or NSData without code? I.e. I need the ability to add and delete questions easily without constantly going into the nitty gritty. This is especially important because I have to copy and paste questions from word files.

Comment: Well, *as an example*, try writing to disk a NSArray which contains 3 or 4 NSDictionary objects each of which contain a question and some answers to choose from.  Then open the file and see how it looks. You can easily add additional NSDictionary objects to the plist file by opening the plist file in Xcode or with Property List Editor.

Comment: Thanks again. Because there are so many questions, I don't think I would be able to go through a plist adding questions and answers. For now, I'll stick with the .txt file. But back to my original question, if I am using this with no problem for now, is it fine to use, or could there be memory problems down the road?

Answer (score 0):

For something like this, I will typically use JSON files, and then use Apple's JSON parsing framework.

Comment: JSON is typically best used in remote-server & iOS-client situations.  I've never seen an instance where data was stored entirely on the iPhone in JSON format.

Comment: Dont see anything wrong with it. I do it frequently. A key advantage is ease of manipulation in non-ObjC languages, I'd rather use python std lib Json API than script plistbuddy if I need to automat production / modification.